# Read Write in Covariance and Contravariance in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

While [learning Java generics](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance) I came to know that with covariance we can read items from a structure, but we cannot write anything into it and with contravariance we can write items into a structure, but we cannot read anything from it.

Let's take an example :

```
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myNums.add(45L); // Covariance - compiler error
List<? super Integer> myNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myNums.add(1);
Number myNum = myNums.get(0); //Contravariance - compiler-error
```

What I am not able to understand is why is this thing prohibited ? I am not able to understand what can go wrong if this thing is allowed to happen ?

Comment: newArrayList need to be new ArrayList

Comment: This talks about what can go wrong with covariance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1

Comment: Well actually the article you linked explains exactly that question. Do you have any concrete questions in regard to these explanation?

Comment: And your own code shows it, too. it tries to add a Long (45L) to a List<Integer>. if it was allowed, the list wouldn't be type-safe anymore, since you would store a Long into a List<Integer>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add element of `Integer` class into `List<? extends Number>` because you don't know exact type of elements in the list. It may be actually `List<Double>`. The same logic in the next example. What you get from `List<? super Integer>` may have `Object` type, not the `Number`.